# Teradata Fast export (or TPT) vs Sqoop export

Tags: hadoop, teradata, sqoop, fastexport

**Edit:** Need to identify which one is better for exporting huge data volume from Teradata - Sqoop, TPT, or fexp

**OP:** I am already aware that teradata's fast export and TPT cannot be used to export data directly to Hadoop. I can bring data to local environment and move it to hadoop parallely.

I want to know which tool extracts the data from Teradata in the most efficient way.

I have to extract dataset having huge data volume (almost 25 billion records ~ 15 TB in size).
Of course the data in Teradata is well partitioned and I am going to split my extraction strategy based on partitions and Unique PI.

I was not able to find enough content which would provide direct comparison between Teradata utilities and Sqoop.

Which tool would make least impact on currently running jobs in Teradata environment and extract the data in most optimized way.

Comment: TPT can be used to export directly to Hadoop, read the links I posted

Answer (score 1):

Of course Teradata's FastExport can't be used to export to Hadoop directly, it's an old legacy tool which is not enhanced anymore.

Any new development should be done using TPT, e.g.

[Using the DataConnector Operator to Write Files and Tables in Hadoop](https://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035-2445%E2%80%90086K/2445ch06.08.5.html#)

[Common Data Movement Jobs](https://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035-2445%E2%80%90086K/2445ch06.08.6.html#)

Comment: In that case, which one is better for exporting huge data volume -  TPT (or) Sqoop ?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting @dnoeth. I have included TPT aswell in my question now. I want to compare Teradata utilities with Sqoop for extraction

Comment: *least impact on currently running jobs in Teradata* should have TPT.